# Low Quality Post Review Queue Options

Tags: discussion, review-queues, low-quality-posts

I recently gained access to the [Low Quality Posts Review Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22423785). I was reviewing an answer, and the answer seemed like it was a good answer. Then I read the comments, and the person who posted the question said that the answer didn't work.

*Do I choose "recommend deletion" for this answer? And if so, what comment should I add?*

I skipped the answer, but what should I do for next time?

Comment: From that queue you delete vote anything that isn't an answer. A bad or not working answer is still an answer. Delete anything that is a comment or a "i have this problem too". Anything else is best skipped.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would argue that it was the [right decision to skip this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252195/1079354) as a review, since you didn't really understand the context of the question nor could you objectively judge whether or not the answer was any good.

Now I'd argue that there's a more fundamental issue with the *question*, since what it's asking for is off-topic by definition...